# Stock Level Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need an algorithm to put orders without stock on hold.

Each order can have multiple products and each its own quantity.

Based on the stock level I would like to know how to determine which orders to put on hold. Possibly the lowest number of orders.

To make it simpler this is an example:

```
Order #1
A 5, B 3, C 10

Order #3
A 1, B 2, C 3

Order #4
A 5, B 5, C 5

Order #5
A 1, B 1, C 1

**Stock Level** 
A = 5, B = 5, C = 5
```

Obviously order #1 needs to go on hold as we do not have 10 of prod C. Now I can fulfill orders #5 and #3 or just order #4. To complicate it more I need this function or another one to release the orders on hold once we have the stock.

This is to be implemented for a scale where approximately 3000 orders are being processed each day.

My approach would be to get all the products that do not have enough stock for all the orders. Then find the smallest combination of orders to place on hold. Possibly considering other products that could be out of stock inside those orders.

Hope you find it as interesting as I do

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: I would try to avoid making a try-all-combinations program because it might be more important to *know* which orders will be processed first, and be able to *explain* why that is. As such I would make the rules simple, and live with slightly more orders put on hold than the minimum. Based on this I would try to create an ordering field that tells you which orders are "best" to fulfill first, and then simply take them in the order they come, if possible. This would work when taking them off hold as well, simply reprocess them to see if they can be fulfilled.

Comment: This is a multidimensional knapsack problem.

Comment: You probably meant "do not have 10 of prod C"

Comment: Usually, order have a priority or are processed in a "first come, first served" fashion. Optimizing 3000 orders with tens of thousands of order lines might take forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instance of a [scheduling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aScheduling_algorithms). You actually want to reduce the maximum latency for any order. Think about it : If you had an infinite stock, orders will go as they come, and everyone will be happy.

You can adapt the principle of the [Multilevel feedback queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_feedback_queue) :

- Each order has a priority
- Order who just get in have lowest priority
- You increase the priority of an order without stock using a priority function `foo(order)`
- Each time you can choose between `j1` and `j2` and you choose `j1`, you increase the priority of `j2` using another priority function `bar(j2)`
- There is also the natural ordering `less(j1,j2)` between jobs. This is the decision between a set of jobs without taking the stock level in consideration.

Now you can tune depending on specific things. The natural ordering maybe `FIFO`, `smaller first`, `bigger first`. You can design priorities such that an order with items out of stock are processed as soon as the stock allows them.

Comment: He should not forget to take care of the concurrent programming issue. This is more an instance of [Lamport's bakery algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport's_bakery_algorithm)

Comment: @eliasah How is that? I didn't see threading as an major issue here.

Comment: and yet he didn't say that he wasn't using an threading. But I never said that it's a major issue. I just added the idea to the stack